# the value contained in my defined object, overwrites the value of my already-defined objects

Tags: java, class, oop, object, math

In my first statement, it printed out the values of hx,

```
matrix hx = X.times(theta);
System.out.println("Value of hx: ");
for (int i =0; i< hx.getRowdimension(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j< hx.getColdimension(); j++) {
        System.out.println(hx.getArray()[i][j]);
    }
}
```

but in my second statement, log_hx overwrites the value of hx. why is that and how to get rid of it?

```
matrix log_hx  = MathUtility.matrixLog(hx);
System.out.println("Value of hx: ");
for (int i =0; i< hx.getRowdimension(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j< hx.getColdimension(); j++) {
        System.out.println(hx.getArray()[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Here's my MathUtility class:

```
public final class MathUtility {

    public static matrix matrixLog(matrix B) {
        int m = B.getRowdimension();
        int n = B.getColdimension();
        double[][] C = B.getArray();
        for (int i = 0; i< m; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j< n; j++) {
                C[i][j] = Math.log(C[i][j]);
            }
        }
        return new matrix(C);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you rewrite the `getArray()` method of your `matrix` class to return a copy of the underlying array instead of the array itself, it should also work.

Also: Please stick to coding conventions. Your class should be called `Matrix`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `B.getArray();` with `new double[m][n]` so you aren't reusing the old array.